# Is Parallel.ForEachAsync a replacement to a plain for loop + append to task list (async await Task.Run)+ WhenAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreachasync

Say I want to make parallel API post requests.

In a for loop I can append the http post call into a list of tasks, (each task invoked using Task.Run) and then wait for all to finish using `await Task.WhenAll`. Thus the control will go to caller while waiting for the network request to complete. Effectively the API request will be made in parallel.

Similarly I can use [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0) which will automatically do the `WhenAll` and return control to caller. So I want to ask whether `ForEachAsync` is a replacement to a plain for loop list (async await Task.Run) and `WhenAll`?

Comment: No,  it's not. `Parallel.ForEach` does a *lot* more than just use multiple tasks. - it partitions the data so that each worker task won't have to synchronize with others to access the data. Then it uses as many workers as there are cores to process those partitions. There's little point in starting 100 workers if there are only 4 cores. The other 96 workers will simply do nothing except add to the scheduling overhead

Comment: `which will automatically do the WaitAll` that's not what happens. `Parallel` will use the current thread to process data, and since all cores are busy crunching data, it appears as if the thread is "blocked". It's not

Comment: A threading equivalent to `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is an `ActionBlock` with a DOP equal to the number of cores, using an async lambda. Even then , an ActionBlock doesn't deal with partitioning, nor does it dynamically alter the number of workers, or handle load balancing the way `Parallel.ForEach` does

Comment: In fact, an ActionBlock would be a *lot* better than a loop and WaitAll. With an ActionBlock you can limit the number of concurrent connections easily. Neither servers nor clients have infinite bandwidth or CPU, so trying to send 100 HTTP requests concurrently can easily be *slower* than making just 10 at a time

Comment: PS: `ForEachAsync` returns a `Task`, so it behaves as if you called `WhenAll`, not `WaitAll`

Comment: I found the [Github issue where ForEachAsync was discussed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946) and it sounds like partitioning is *not* used. `ForEach` and `ForEachAsync` pass state between workers and iterations though, something not possible with either a loop of tasks or `ActionBlock. And as [the source shows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L88) it doesn't just start some tasks.

Comment: So parallel for each used 1 core per task. Where as async await makes use of 1 thread per task?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you could consider moving your comments into a new answer. Comments are intended for asking for more information or suggesting improvements. Answering questions in comments [should be avoided](https://prnt.sc/RfK7kkKxohGr "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.").

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I know the distinction very well. In fac, given it's a year since I posted the comment, I don't think that's what this comment is about.

Answer (score 14):

No, the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0) API has quite a lot of differences compared to a trivial use of the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) API:

1. The elephant in the room: the `await Task.WhenAll` returns an array with the results of the asynchronous operations. On the contrary the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` returns a naked `Task`. If you want the results you must rely on side-effects, like updating a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` as part of the asynchronous operation.
2. The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` invokes the supplied asynchronous delegate in parallel, on `ThreadPool` threads ([configurable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler)). On the contrary the common pattern of using the `Task.WhenAll` is to create the `Task`s sequentially, on the current thread. This raises concerns about using the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` in ASP.NET applications, where offloading work on the `ThreadPool` might have [scalability implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764366/is-task-run-considered-bad-practice-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application).
3. The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` invokes the asynchronous delegate and awaits the generated tasks, while enforcing a maximum level of concurrency equal to `Environment.ProcessorCount`. This behavior is configurable through the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option. On the contrary the common pattern of using the `Task.WhenAll` is to create all the tasks at once, imposing no concurrency limitation.
4. The common pattern of using the `Task.WhenAll` is to assume that creating all the tasks is impossible to fail midway, and so to take no precautions against this possibility. In case this actually happens, fire-and-forget tasks might be leaked. This is not possible with the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API.
5. The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will stop invoking the asynchronous delegate as soon as the first error occurs on either an asynchronous delegate invocation, or a created `Task`, and then propagates a failure containing all the errors that have occurred so far, after awaiting all the already created tasks. It also provides a mechanism for canceling the other tasks that are in-flight when the error occurs (the `CancellationToken` that is passed as second argument in the lambda). On the contrary the `Task.WhenAll` waits invariably for all the tasks to complete. This means that you might have to wait for a lot longer, before eventually receiving an `AggregateException` containing the errors of all the tasks that have failed.

Comment: I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/71129678#71129678 "ForEachAsync with Result") a `ForEachAsync` variant that returns results.

Comment: Hi, nice answer, just wondering do you know the performance difference between the two? I am more interested in speed.

Comment: the reason I ask is that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778189/how-to-improve-speed-for-multiple-npgsql-connections not sure which way to go, or do you have any ideas thanks.

Comment: @AndySong probably the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` as a mechanism has more overhead than the `Task.WhenAll`, but the difference should be in the scale of nanoseconds. The overhead of either mechanism is unlikely to have any noticeable effect in the performance of your app though. On the other hand the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` by being able to control the degree of parallelism might result in a smoother communication pattern with your database, resulting in big time performance improvements. If your database is happy, your app will be happy too!

Comment: "This raises concerns about using the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` in ASP.NET applications, where offloading work on the `ThreadPool` might have scalability implications."  To confirm, you talking specifically about scenarios in which your delegate contains CPU-intensive code prior to `await`, right?  Meaning using `ForEachAsync` would clog up multiple CPU cores while kicking off the collection of tasks, whereas you'd normally kick the tasks off one at a time and avoid that issue.

Comment: @MarredCheese I am not talking about CPU-bound code. This is obviously bad in ASP.NET. Stephen Cleary has written in multiple occasions that `Task.Run` in ASP.NET is bad, even with async delegates, because it throws off the thread pool heuristics. If `Task.Run` is bad, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` should be even worse. I am a sceptic to this claim, but Stephen Cleary is an expert in this field. Links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966172/11178549), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065172/11178549), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202809/).