# Send the progress bar as a parameter to a function in another class that return Task<bool> Type

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, async-await, invoke

I want to send a progress bar that is available on my form to a function to display the progress of the operation of that function and finally return true if everything is fine and return false if else
The operation inside the `SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile` function is executed asynchronously so as not to interfere with the execution of other operations.
When the program runs and the compiler calls the line `_ProgressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {_ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(i);}));` Inside the `badCustomers.SendToDB(progressBar_BadCustomers)` function, there is no feedback and the program seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.
But if the output of the `SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile` function is defined as void, everything works fine.

My code when the system hangs:

In Button:

```
private void btn_ChoiceBadCustomersFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("message", "title",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if ((dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes))
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {                        
                result = GetDataFromExcelFile.SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(
                    progressBar_BadCustomers).Result;
            }
            catch
            {
                result = false;
            }
            if (result)
            {
                //code...
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //code...
    }
}
```

Code In GetDataFromExcelFile.SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(...)

```
public static class GetDataFromExcelFile
{
    public async static Task<bool> SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(
        DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ProgressBarX progressBar_BadCustomers)
    {
        try
        {
            PoomaDbAppEntities DB10 = new PoomaDbAppEntities();
            IQueryable<tbl_BadCustomers> dt = null;
            MyExcelWorkSpace _excelApp = new MyExcelWorkSpace();
            MyExcelWorkSpace.badCustomers badCustomers = new MyExcelWorkSpace
                .badCustomers();
            string path = badCustomers.select();
            if (path != String.Empty)
            {
                if (badCustomers.Open(path))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => { dt = badCustomers
                            .SendToDB(progressBar_BadCustomers); });
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And In badCustomers.SendToDB(...) :

```
public class badCustomers : ExcelFile, IStartWorkWithExcelFile<tbl_BadCustomers>
{
    //code
    public IQueryable<tbl_BadCustomers> SendToDB(DevComponents.DotNetBar
        .Controls.ProgressBarX _ProgressBar)
    {
            try
            {
                //code
                _ProgressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
                    _ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(i); }));
            }
            catch
            {
                //code
            }
        }
        IQueryable<tbl_BadCustomers> dt = DB10.tbl_BadCustomers.Select(i => i);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

If the `SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile` function is defined as below, the program works, but I need to know if an error has occurred or not.

```
public async static void SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(
    DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ProgressBarX progressBar_BadCustomers)
{
    //code
}
```

If the `SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile` function is defined as below, the program works, but I need to know if an error has occurred or not.

```
public async static void SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(
    DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ProgressBarX progressBar_BadCustomers)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Usually, you pass a `IProgress<YourProgressStruct>` to the async method. The caller can easily wire this up to a progress bar using the `Progress<T>` class. You will find some examples also on StackOverflow, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652535/using-iprogress-when-reporting-progress-for-async-await-code-vs-progress-bar-con

Comment: `result= GetDataFromExcelFile.SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile(progressBar_BadCustomers).Result;` - lookin' for trouble, hah ;D - Fun aside: If it's async, await it.

Comment: Usually when reporting progress there is a loop somewhere that does the reporting, I cannot see any such loop in the example. But it *does* report using an `i`, and that makes me worried about the overall design. But you should most likely use `Progress<T>` or something equivalent.

Comment: Take the IProgress<T> reporting procedure from, e.g, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103), it's also meant to update a ProgressBar -- In this platform, never (ever) use `.Wait()` or the `.Result` of Tasks you don't await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no feedback and the program seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

This is because [the code is using `Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html); full details on my blog.

To solve this, you want to [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void) (i.e., for `SaveBadCustomerMustStayMasdoodExcelFile`); `async void` is intended for event handlers, so you can make `btn_ChoiceBadCustomersFile_Click` an `async void` method. Everything else should use `await` and `async Task`.

As far as the Progress goes, I echo the recommendations in the comments: `IProgress<T>` with `Progress<T>` makes your code cleaner (e.g., no `Invoke` necessary).