# How can I gather results from parallel async tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-5, parallel.foreach

I'm actually facing a problem with parallelism on asynchronous tasks.

My goal is to have an async `Task` which connects to multiple endpoints to retrieve the same kind of data. A list with all "connection strings" is provided. The data retrieval shall happen in parallel with all connections and the retrieved data of each connection shall be merged into a single container which will be returned, once all parallel async tasks finished.

My first idea was using `AsParallel.ForAll()` - passing the configurations, and an async Task to fill a (Dataflow) `BufferBlock` with `SendAsync`. Now I got stuck on the problem, that `Parallel` queries seem to only take `Action<T>` as parameter and not `Task<T>`. This will lead to an undesired behavior if an exception occurs.

Does anyone have a better approach to my problem?

Here is a snippet for better visualization:

```
configurations.AsParallel().ForAll(async config => await FetchAllData(config,
    resultBufferBlock, cancellationToken));
```

After some comments: I basically need `Parallel.ForEachAsync` which is available in .NET 6. we will move to .NET 6 in a couple of months. This is already planned. Although I would appreciate a solution for .NET 5. Actually it looks like I will use the bad way using the task as Action and fix that later…

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? `Parallel.ForEachAsync` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0

Comment: Is this helpful? [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations) Or this? [Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda)

Comment: @maksymiuk I recently learned the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is .net 6 _(it is tagged .net 5)_

Comment: @maksymiuk yes! Didn't come accross this because it's .Net 6 and currently we are on .Net 5. I'm already happy this problem is solved in .Net 6. Anyway I need a solution before we move to .NET 6 (we will probably do it in a couple of months).

Comment: @OttoV. Ah I didn't catch the `.net-5` tag

Comment: A custom implementation of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` (one of many) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949).

Comment: There's also the actual source code for the .NET 6 implementation of ForEachAsync: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm actually facing a problem with parallelism on asynchronous tasks.

The problem you describe is concurrency (doing more than one thing at a time) and AFAICT does not need parallelism (multiple threads).

> Does anyone have a better approach to my problem?

The way to do asynchronous concurrency is to start all the tasks (commonly using a LINQ select with an asynchronous lambda), and then use `Task.WhenAll` to join them.

```
var tasks = configurations.Select(async config => await FetchAllData(config, resultBufferBlock, cancellationToken));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

> After some comments: I basically need Parallel.ForEachAsync which is available in .NET 6.

I disagree. `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is for when you have a complex mixture of CPU-bound and I/O-bound code and need to do both parallelism *and* asynchronous concurrency. In this case parallelism isn't necessary.