# Parallelizing execution with Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to improve performane of some code which does some shopping function calling number of different vendors. 3rd party vendor call is async and results are processed to generate a result. Strucure of the code is as follows.

```
public async Task<List<ShopResult>> DoShopping(IEnumerable<Vendor> vendors)
    {
        var res = vendors.Select(async s => await DoShopAndProcessResultAsync(s));
        await Task.WhenAll(res); ....
    }
```

Since DoShopAndProcessResultAsync is both IO bound and CPU bound, and each vendor iteration is independant I think Task.Run can be used to do something like below.

```
public async Task<List<ShopResult>> DoShopping(IEnumerable<Vendor> vendors)
    {
        var res = vendors.Select(s => Task.Run(() => DoShopAndProcessResultAsync(s)));
        await Task.WhenAll(res); ...
    }
```

Using Task.Run as is having a performance gain and I can see multiple threads are being involved here from the order of execution of the calls. And it is running without any issue locally on my machine.
However, it is a tasks of tasks scenario and wondering whether any pitfalls or this is deadlock prone in a high traffic prod environment.

What are your opinions on the approach of using Task.Run to parallelize async calls?

Comment: In the first snippet, how about `var res = vendors.Select(DoShopAndProcessResultAsync);` to get a bunch of tasks, then use `await Task.WhenAll(res);`?

Comment: I'm doing something similar using a `SemaphoreSlim` in this post: https://blog.elmah.io/bulk-download-from-azure-blob-storage-with-c/

Comment: Parallelism isn't Concurrency isn't Asynchronous execution. .NET can already handle *concurrent* execution using high-level libraries like Dataflow blocks, or System.Threading.Channel+IAsyncEnumerable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"Parallelism isn't Concurrency isn't Asynchronous execution"* -- How is this relevant to the question asked? More specifically, does your comment suggest an improvement for the question asked? If yes, what exactly is this suggested improvement?

Comment: I know you know and that I've already explained that dozens of times in duplicate questions, but I'll repeat it for those that haven't seen the duplicates. Parallelism in .NET means specifically CPU-bound, in-memory data parallelism: processing lots of in-memory data using all available cores. Concurrency means executing lots of jobs, possibly related and often IO-bound, at the same time. The two different paradigms require different optimizations, which is why `Parallel.ForEach` is terrible for concurrent work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I asked you how is your comment relevant to the question, and how it contributes in the improvement of the question. I didn't ask for your definition of parallelism. Which is a controversial definition btw, as you'll probably find out if you post it as an answer to a relevant question, so that people can evaluate (vote) it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What is alarming with the `Task.Run` approach in your question, is that it depletes the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) from available worker threads in a non-controlled manner. It doesn't offer any configuration option that would allow you to reduce the parallelism of each individual request, in favor of preserving the scalability of the whole service. That's something that might bite you in the long run.

Ideally you would like to control both the parallelism and the concurrency, and control them independently. For example you might want to limit the maximum concurrency of the I/O-bound work to 10, and the maximum parallelism of the CPU-bound work to 2. Regarding the former you could take a look at this question: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Regarding the later, you could use a [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) with limited concurrency. The [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair) is a handy class for this purpose. Here is an example of how you could rewrite your `DoShopping` method in a way that limits the `ThreadPool` usage to two threads at maximum (per request), without limiting at all the concurrency of the I/O-bound work:

```
public async Task<ShopResult[]> DoShopping(IEnumerable<Vendor> vendors)
{
    var scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
        TaskScheduler.Default, maxConcurrencyLevel: 2).ConcurrentScheduler;

    var tasks = vendors.Select(vendor =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoShopAndProcessResultAsync(vendor),
            default, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, scheduler).Unwrap();
    });

    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

**Important:** In order for this to work, the `DoShopAndProcessResultAsync` method should be implemented internally without [`.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) at the `await` points. Otherwise the continuations after the `await` will not run on our preferred `scheduler`, and the goal of limiting the `ThreadPool` utilization will be defeated.

My personal preference though would be to use instead the new (.NET 6) [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API. Apart from making it easy to control the concurrency through the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option, it also comes with a better behavior in case of exceptions. Instead of launching invariably *all* the async operations, it stops launching new operations as soon as a previously launched operation has failed. This can make a big difference in the responsiveness of your service, in case for example that all individual async operations are failing with a timeout exception. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544324/is-parallel-foreachasync-a-replacement-to-a-plain-for-loop-append-to-task-list/68581885#68581885) a synopsis of the main differences between the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) APIs.

Unfortunately the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` has the disadvantage that it doesn't return the results of the async operations. Which means that you have to collect the results manually as a side-effect of each async operation. I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/71129678#71129678) a `ForEachAsync` variant that returns results, that combines the best aspects of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and the `Task.WhenAll` APIs. You could use it like this:

```
public async Task<ShopResult[]> DoShopping(IEnumerable<Vendor> vendors)
{
    var scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
        TaskScheduler.Default, maxConcurrencyLevel: 2).ConcurrentScheduler;

    ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };

    return await ForEachAsync(vendors, options, async (vendor, ct) =>
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoShopAndProcessResultAsync(vendor),
            ct, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, scheduler).Unwrap();
    });
}
```

---

**Note:** In my initial answer ([revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72766035/1)) I had suggested erroneously to pass the `scheduler` through the [`ParallelOptions.TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler) property. I just found out that this doesn't work as I expected. The `ParallelOptions` class has an internal property [`EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/844b0999fde67cdbaa7acb0f398ea1b066a2b8c7/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L107-L119) that represents the minimum of the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and the `TaskScheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel`. The [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/844b0999fde67cdbaa7acb0f398ea1b066a2b8c7/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs) of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method uses this property, instead of reading directly the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. So the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, by being larger than the `MaximumConcurrencyLevel`, was effectively ignored.

You've probably also noticed by now that the names of these two settings are confusing. We use the `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` in order to control the number of threads (aka the parallelization), and we use the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in order to control the amount of concurrent async operations (aka the concurrency). The reason for this confusing terminology can be traced to the historic origins of these APIs. The `ParallelOptions` class was introduced before the async-await era, and the designers of the new `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API aimed at making it compatible with the older non-asynchronous members of the `Parallel` class.

Comment: After thinking about it, I now believe that the behavior of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` that invalidated my initial answer is a bug. I've posted a [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/71415 "Parallel.ForEachAsync the TaskScheduler and MaxDegreeOfParallelism options interfere with each other") on GitHub about it.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks are .NET's low-level building blocks. .NET almost always has a better high-level abstraction for specific concurrency paradigms.

---

To paraphrase [Rob Pike](https://vimeo.com/49718712) ([slides](https://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#1)) `Concurrency is not parallelism is not asynchronous execution`. What you ask is concurrent execution, with a specific degree-of-parallelism. NET already offers high-level classes that can do that, without resorting to low-level task handling.

At the end, I explain why these distinctions matter and how they're implemented using different .NET classes or libraries

**Dataflow blocks**

At the highest level, the Dataflow classes allow creating a pipeline of processing blocks similar to a Powershell or Bash pipeline, where each block can use one or more tasks to process input. Dataflow blocks preserve message order, ensuring results are emitted in the order the input messages were received.

You'll often see combinations of block called meshes, not pipelines. Dataflow grew out of the Microsoft Robotics Framework and can be used to create a network of independent processing blocks. Most programmers just use to build a pipeline of steps though.

In your case, you could use a `TransformBlock` to execute `DoShopAndProcessResultAsync` and feed the output either to another processing block, or a BufferBlock you can read after processing all results. You could even split Shop and Process into separate blocks, each with its own logic and degree of parallelism

Eg.

```
var buffer=new BufferBlock<ShopResult>();
var blockOptions=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism=3, 
        BoundedCapacity=1 
};
var shop=new TransformBlock<Vendor,ShopResult)(DoShopAndProcessResultAsync,
                                               blockOptions);

var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions{ PropagateCompletion=true;}
shop.LinkTo(buffer,linkOptions);

foreach(var v in vendors)
{
    await shop.SendAsync(v);
}

shop.Complete();
await shop.Completion;

buffer.TryReceiveAll(out IList<ShopResult> results);
```

You can use two separate blocks to shop and process :

```
var shop=new TransformBlock<Vendor,ShopResponse>(DoShopAsync,shopOptions);
var process=new TransformBlock<ShopResponse,ShopResult>(DoProcessAsync,processOptions);

shop.LinkTo(process,linkOptions);
process.LinkTo(results,linkOptions);

foreach(var v in vendors)
{
    await shop.SendAsync(v);
}

shop.Complete();
await process.Completion;
```

In this case we await the completion of the last block in the chain before reading the results.

Instead of reading from a buffer block, we could use an ActionBlock at the end to do whatever we want to do with the results, eg store them to a database. The results can be batched using a BatchBlock to reduce the number of storage operations

```
...
var batch=new BatchBlock<ShopResult>(100);
var store=new ActionBlock<ShopResult[]>(DoStoreAsync);

shop.LinkTo(process,linkOptions);
process.LinkTo(batch,linkOptions);
batch.LinkTo(store,linkOptions);

...
shop.Complete();
await store.Completion;
```

**Why do names matter**

Tasks are the lowest level building blocks used to implement multiple paradigms. In other languages you'd see them described as Futures or Promises (eg Javascript)

*Parallelism* in .NET means executing CPU-bound computations over a lot of data using all available cores. `Parallel.ForEach` will partition the input data into roughly as many partitions as there are cores and use one worker task per partition. PLINQ goes one step further, allowing the use of LINQ operators to specify the computation and let PLINQ to use algorithms optimized for parallel execution to map, filter, sort, group and collect results. That's why `Parallel.ForEach` can't be used for async work at all.

*Concurrency* means executing multiple independent and often IO-bound jobs. At the lowest level you can use Tasks but Dataflow, Rx.NET, Channels, IAsyncEnumerable etc allow the use of high-level patterns like CSP/Pipelines, event stream processing etc

*Asynchronous execution* means you don't have to block while waiting for I/O-bound work to complete.