# How to improve speed for multiple npgsql connections

Tags: c#, postgresql, performance, .net-core, npgsql

```cs
var sqlDbLink = $"SELECT * FROM example;";

foreach ( var db in databases ) {
        var connStr = sqlConnectionService.GetConnectionString(db.Name);
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr)) {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        var cmd = GetPostgresCommand(conn, sqlDbLink);
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                await reader.ReadAsync();
                db.ComparisonDatabaseName = reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are around 40 items in databases, and it's slow (that's the time-consuming part), the main part is `await conn.OpenAsync();`. I used `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, and the time got 60% reduced, any other ideas that can improve this? Assuming we are not going to change the db structure.

Comment: _" and it's slow"_ - how have you tested it and what have you compared it to?

Comment: @GuruStron sorry I did not mean it's slower than other things (or other ways of opening connection), I am just pointing out that that's the time-consuming part, maybe i should change the description.

Comment: A few things that you could try, and report if they make any difference: 1. Replace the `*` in the `SELECT * FROM example` with the specific field that you are interested to read. 2. Configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to various values, like 2, 4, 10, 20, 100. 3. Find what available options exist for optimizing the connection string. You could also use a dedicated `Stopwatch` per database, and log the duration of opening the connection and executing the command for each database. Then report back these metrics, they might be useful.

Comment: Do you use a connection pool like pgBouncer?

Comment: @FrankHeikens unless there are duplicates in `databases` there is no reason to pool the connections.